# WriteProcessMemory não escreve os dados

Tags: c#

Olá! Eu estou tentando escrever dados na memoria do tipo INT, e não está funcionando, o ReadProcessMemory funcionou normalmente! Porém o WriteProcessMemory não.

Eu não sei se estou fazendo algo de errado mais se puderem ajudar agradeço!

Código que tenho até agora.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace CSGO_InfiniteAmmo
{
    class Program
    {

        [DllImport("Kernel32.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr OpenProcess(int dwDesiredAccess, bool bInheritHandle, int dwProcessId);

        [DllImport("Kernel32.dll")]
        private static extern Boolean ReadProcessMemory(IntPtr hProcess, int lpBaseAddress, out int lpBuffer, int nSize, int lpNumberOfBytesRead);
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        static extern bool WriteProcessMemory(
            IntPtr hProcess,
            IntPtr lpBaseAddress,
            byte[] lpBuffer,
            int dwSize,
            out IntPtr lpNumberOfBytesWritten);
        private const int PROCESS_VM_READ = 0x0010;
        static private int pId = 0;
        static private int lpBaseAddress = 0x0058059C;
        static private int getAdressValue = 0;
        static IntPtr hProcess = IntPtr.Zero;

        static void Main()
        {
            pId = Process.GetProcessesByName("project")[0].Id;
            if (pId == 0)
                return;

            hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_VM_READ, false, pId);

            if (ReadProcessMemory(hProcess, 0x6A4ED8E4, out getAdressValue, 4, 0))
                Console.WriteLine("Output: " + getAdressValue.ToString());

            Write(hProcess, 0x6A4ED8E4, 25);
        }

        static bool Write(IntPtr handle, int address, int valor)
        {
            byte[] dataBuffer = { (byte)5 };
            IntPtr bytesWritten = IntPtr.Zero;

            WriteProcessMemory(handle, (IntPtr)address, dataBuffer, dataBuffer.Length, out bytesWritten);

            Console.WriteLine(bytesWritten);
            if (bytesWritten == IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Não foi escrito nenhum valor!");
                return false;
            }
            if (bytesWritten.ToInt32() < dataBuffer.Length)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(" Escrevemos {0} de {1} bytes!", bytesWritten.ToInt32(), dataBuffer.Length.ToString());
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Na linha em que abre o processo `hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_VM_READ, false, pId);`  você passa para o parâmetro `DWORD dwDesiredAccess` o valor `PROCESS_VM_READ` se consultar a [documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/process-security-and-access-rights) verá que o valor é necessário para ler a memória em um processo que usa `ReadProcessMemory()` mas não `WriteProcessMemory()`. Para usar `WriteProcessMemory()` passe como parâmetro `dwDesiredAccess` o valor `PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS` ou então `PROCESS_VM_READ | PROCESS_VM_WRITE`

Answer (score -1):

Aqui segue um exemplo de como usar a função:

```
public bool Wpm<T>(IntPtr lpBaseAddress, T value) where T : struct
    {
        var buffer = new T[Marshal.SizeOf<T>()];
        buffer[0] = value;
        return WriteProcessMemory(_gameProcess.Process.Handle, lpBaseAddress, buffer, Marshal.SizeOf<T>(), out var bytesread);
    }
```

[referência do código](https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/WriteProcessMemory.html)

Tente modificar seu codigo para ficar similar ao do exemplo, especialmente da maneira com que você está criado o buffer, e accessando o valor do tamnho do buffer, tente usar `Marshal.SizeOf<byte>()`.